# Is there a guide to the publication history of the X-Men?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

I mean, there's a Wikipedia article entitled "Publication history of X-men comics," but it's vastly incomplete.

I'm looking for a TOTAL map showing every single strain of comics released by Marvel since 1963 chronicling the X-Men, any individual X-Men, any and all spin-offs that distinctly originated from the X-Men (X-Factor, X-Force, New Mutants, Excalibur, etc) and parallel timelines and revamps...I mean EVERYTHING.

I've always thought of the X-Men universe as this vast and unknowable thing; it seems the comics branch in so many places that it's impossible to keep track of how many different concurrent series there are.

I want to understand more clearly what there is, when each branch started (both the publication date and the time within the story relative to the greater chronology, if the latter information exists), when it ended, what it was about in general, and whether it was in keeping with the overall chronology or whether it completely disavowed past events to create its own unique path.

Does such a guide exist? Could be a book, could be a gigantic chart somewhere on the internet, or something like that.

Comment: Give me a free week with GIMP, and I'll do my best. This sounds like fun. Challenge accepted.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage how's it going? I gave you about 5 and a half years with GIMP. :)

Comment: 5 and half years and still no free week :(

Comment: @AncientSwordRage you could probably make a GoFundMe for this or something. People would dig it. I'm still waiting and it's been 8 years since the original question and your comment. Although I think it'd have to be more along the lines of an interactive webapp than a single image from GIMP given the sheer scale of the information. Probably would take more than a week, too :D

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best X-chronology up to the 90s:
[X-title timelines - Chronology.net](http://www.chronology.net/default.pl/timelines)

For only X-titles, this is a pretty complete list:
[The Definitive X-Men Reading Order Guide - Crushing Krisis](http://crushingkrisis.com/crushing-comics-guide-collecting-marvel-comic-books/x-men-reading-order-guide/)

Comment: "Link-only answers" are heavily frowned upon. If your link goes dead, your answer becomes worthless

Comment: @Valorum - I think this would be the rare case where the link *is* the answer.